# Separation of a weak-star closed wedge by a weak-star continuous linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis

First of all, a wedge in a vector space is a convex set which is invariant under multiplication by positive real numbers.

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, nonempty, convex sets in a locally convex topological vector space $X$ such that $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed, then part (b) of Theorem 3.4 in Rudin's Functional Analysis book guarantees the existence of a bounded linear functional $\Lambda$ on $X$, whose real part separates $A$ from $B$, i.e., there exist two real numbers $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ such that
$$Re\Lambda x < \gamma_1 < \gamma_2 < Re\Lambda y$$ for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$.

I am interested in a particular case. Let $X(=Z^*)$ be a Banach space. Suppose $A$ and $B$ are as above with an extra fact that $B$ is weak-star closed (hence norm closed) wedge in $X$. Does there exist a **weak-star continuous** linear functional $\Lambda$ whose real part separates $A$ from $B$ in the above sense?

Comment: Which properties do you have for $A$? If $A$ is compact w.r.t. the weak-star topology, you can just invoke the above theorem.

Comment: I shall check whether $A$ is weak-star compact. Thank you for your comment @gerw.